# Finding a value in a range

Tags: python, syntax, range

```
def shazday(y):
    if y >= 1200 or <= 1299:
        x = 4
```

I keep getting syntax on the "=" just before 1299, any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to find any value between these two numbers to assign a variable. I've tried range itself as well but couldn't get it to work. If I could just find out how to properly check for a value in a range in Python, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if y >= 1200 or y <= 1299:
```

But you probably mean:

```
if 1200 <= y <= 1299:
```

Comment: Or alternatively `if y >= 1200 and y <= 1299:` because Python is the only language (that I know of) which supports the `a < x < c` syntax and it might confuse people.

Comment: The weird thing is that although this method works (I've tried it), I don't get the return value of "4" when I run this function.

Such as
>> Shazday.shazday(1200)
>> (BLANK)

Comment: @Shaz You aren't returning anything; its value will be lost when you get out of the function

Comment: @Shaz you need to `return` your return value e.g. `return x`.

Comment: Oh my god. I'm so stupid, you're right! Sorry, I'm a real beginner. Thank you so much for your help, it worked. Just defined x = 4 before returning x itself. I also had to re-assign a value to x each time as I have several ranges, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way, in the `if` statement you want to evaluate several conditions. So we break it down

```
if y >= 1200 or <= 1299:
```

Is y >= 1200? Let's say yes.

```
if true or <= 1299
```

Next we ask is... wait a minute? There's nothing there to compare to! `(blank) <= 1299` and the system has no idea what `(blank)` is supposed to be, so it yells at you until you give it something. In this case we have to tell it to check `y`

```
if y >= 1200 or y <= 1299:
                ^
```

Another way to form this is below, still satisfying that each comparison has something to compare to

```
if 1200 <= y <= 1299:

# this can be thought of as below
if 1200 <= y and
           y <= 1299:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def shazday(y):
    if y >= 1200 or y <= 1299:
        x = 4
```

Note the `y` before the second `<=`. While `y is greater equal or smaller equal` is valid in the English language and everybody understands the meaning, this does not work for programming languages...

What the interpreter does is something like

```
(y >= 1200) is it true or false?
(y <= 1299) is it true or false?
```

...and then applies the logical operator `or`. If the second `y` is missing, the compiler does not know what actually should be smaller equal 1299.

Edit:

Besides the missing `y` you may also change `or` to `and`. Otherwise, the condition will always be true because every number is `>= 1200` or `>=1299`.

Comment: @NullUserException Yes, but that was not the question.